# Creating a plugin in the provider client

Tags: yagna

I am looking to create a plugin on yagna where providers will only accept tasks from whitelisted requestors utilizing private/public keys for authentication.

Are there any documentation or how can I go about doing it? Workflow as follows:

1. Requestor sends task in a specific subnet(do requestors also need a plugin, or are yagna ids unique?)
2. Providers on that subnet check if it's a whitelisted requestor by checking yagna id or other task information which cannot be faked

I am not entirely sure on how I would format it because I don't know how the system works behind the scenes - so any advice there might be necessary if my workflow is too bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a nice idea & it's doable.

You can differentiate requestors by their id's. To get the nodes' id (requestor or provider) just run `yagna id list` (yagna daemon has to be running - `yagna service run`).

Probably the most challenging part would be to modify `ReactToProposal` handler of `CompositeNegotiator`. [Current implementation](https://github.com/golemfactory/yagna/blob/830288196bff943f8819a633041acf55fe78fbf5/agent/provider/src/market/negotiator/composite.rs#L55-L87) casts `Proposal` (`Demand` in this context) into `ProposalView`. Unfotunatelly at this point `requestor_id` is lost. For testing purposes you can just filter requestors directly in `fn handle()` and return `Ok(ProposalResponse::RejectProposal {....})` when you want to block a requestor. Your field of interest is `msg.demand.issuer_id`.

If you want to introduce some kind of public/private key pair functionality, it could achieved by adding custom * demand/offer constraint* that is understood by both your requestor and provider. Unfortunately at this time there is no public documentation on this topic.

Please feel free to reach out if you have further questions.